# raw_input based integer to binary program

Tags: python, binary, integer

I'm trying to make a small little program where a user types in a number and that number is converted to binary and sent back to the user.

I've built it, my only problem is, the "0b" that's at the start I feel would confuse a user who is unfamiliar to binary. Here's my code so far:

```
newInt = input("Enter a number: ")
newInt2 = int(newInt)
binaryInt = bin(newInt2)
print binaryInt
```

It works fine, I just need to remove the "0b" that is at the start of each binary value that gets printed.

Comment: I don’t know if there’s a better way than by slicing it: `print binaryInt[2:]`

Comment: Thanks! Definitely helped. Haven't really heard much about slicing before, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it then......

```
binaryInt[2:]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [4]: bin(143)
Out[4]: '0b10001111'

In [5]: format(143, 'b')
Out[5]: '10001111'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
newInt = input("Enter a number: ")
newInt2 = int(newInt)
binaryInt = bin(newInt2)
x = list(binaryInt)
del x[0:2]
print ''.join(x)
```

Comment: That’s a really verbose way to do it. Does it have an advantage over `binaryInt[2:]`?

Comment: @minitech Thanks, `binaryInt[2:]` is the better answer, my bad.